# configuration proxy in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, redirect, proxy, webserver, virtualhost

Good day,

As my understanding. Forward proxy is something like a middle man to help to do redirect.

For example, I have a web application, and I want to call a web services. And I want it to go through a proxy.

So it will become something like follow:
Application --> proxy server --> web services

However, I found something from internet which is I not understand. The proxy configuration is configure at `httpd.conf`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

As my understanding, this means that any request with "/" will direct to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`.

I am start confuse here, this is something like doing redirect, is it anything related to proxy? If yes, where to put the proxy IP?

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

The proxy IP is already declared in the server block by declaring

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

It like saying tha on the local IP port 80, yu have a virtual server doing whatever is in the server block.

The difference between redirecting and proxying is that in redirect you are redirected to a different URL.

> For example if you redirect the above, if you hit localhost:80 --->
>   localhost:8080

Check out the [ProxyRemote directive for proxying](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyremote) remote if that's the matter.